# How to make a weak reference set in Swift

Tags: swift, foundation, xcode6

NSSet holds strong references to its objects so the Objective C solution was to use NSHashTable.weakObjectsHashTable() a la

```
NSHashTable* mySet = [NSHashTable weakObjectsHashTable];
[mySet addObject:anyOldObject];
[mySet count]; //returns 1
[mySet containsObject:anyOldObject]; //returns true
```

in swift however this does not seem to work

```
var mySet = NSHashTable.weakObjectsHashTable()
mySet.addObject(anyOldObject)
mySet.count //returns 1
mySet.containsObject(anyOldObject) //returns false
```

What am I missing?  Or is this a bug?

Comment: Would you expect mySet.allObjects to return a non-empty array, too? Because it doesn't seem to.

Comment: Yeah I was leaving that as an exercise for the reader :)  I don't get it at all

Comment: Nope, me neither. I can't pretend to know much about weakObjectsHashTable, but it certainly *feels* buggy.

Comment: Interesting. In beta 5, allObjects returns me what I'd expect, but the containsObject still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I had a similar issue with adding a swift object to a `NSHashTable` holding weak references. I had to make the swift object a subclass of `NSObject` for it to be added to the hash table

Answer (score 1):

On Xcode6b5 and using a string as the anyOldObject, I am able to see a return true happening. There were some bugs in 6b4 that prevented optional values from being returned in the interpreter which meant they were being aggressively cleaned up - it might be a problem like this which had the same effect here. It's worth re-trying to see if you have the same behaviour in the latest beta.

Comment: Don't know about the OP, but I am still having these issues with iOS9.0 betas. The blasted thing just doesn't seem to hold onto its contents.